# The use of the word "lend" in context

Tags: word-usage

Can I use *lend* to mean something helps something? For example:

> Learning other languages **lends** to understanding your native one.

Comment: Did you mean **leads**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We normally expect the "indirect object" of ***lend*** (literal or figurative) to be a ***noun***, not an infinitive-based clause. So *in theory*, OP's example could be "corrected" to...

> 1: *Learning other languages lends [you, one] **an understanding of** your native one.*

I can't say *exactly* why that one doesn't work for me, whereas...

> 2: *Learning other languages lends [you] **an air of sophistication***.

...seems perfectly okay. Note that the figurative usage (and indeed the *literal* sense) normally involves something being *temporarily* "reassigned". But in constructions like those above, ***lends*** would more accurately be understood as equivalent to ***confers upon***.

---

It may be that the only reason I don't like #1 (whereas I'm quite happy with #2), is because the figurative usage isn't all that common in general. But the specific collocation [***lends an air of***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lends%20an%20air%20of%22&oq=%22lends%20an%20air%20of%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.13406249j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) *[authority, authenticity, whatever]* is actually quite common - it's something of a "set phrase".

***OR*** it's possible the reason ***an air / appearance*** [of some quality] is particularly likely to be "lent" is because *appearing* to have that quality isn't really the same as *actually* having it (you only seem to have it because of something about your context that temporarily gives that impression). In which context it's worth noting that...

> 3: *His deep voice lends authority to his words*

...could be seen as *temporarily* making the words seem [more] authoritative, in that the implication is they *wouldn't* be so "authoritative" if spoken by someone else with a reedier voice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *lend* in the sense you want, but the sentence needs to be rephrased.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*lend*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lend):

> **2 b** : to adapt or apply (oneself) readily : ACCOMMODATE
>   // a topic that *lends* itself admirably to class discussion

So, in terms of your sentence, it should be rephrased to something like this:

> ？ Learning other languages lends to understanding your native one.
>
> → ✔ *The* learning *of* other languages lends *itself* to understanding your native one.

Comment: Yes, with itself, for sure.